# Decompress a package with .file extension with java code

Tags: java, file, gzip, tar

I need to decompress a  package has ".File" extension. Though manually i can decompress this file with zip or 7zip using openwith in windows.

Note: If i am changing the extension to .zip manually. It is failing to open.

I checked its opening fine in terminal using tar -xvf MYFILE

looking for java code help which work in all platform to decompress the file.

Comment: You **can't** decompress a non-zip file with a zip API.

Comment: Apache compress API has support for 7zip and other compression apis

Comment: can  u please help me with some link, where i can find help to decompress  a .File packages. i could not find any on proper help on ggl.

Comment: because it isn't a zip file. it may be gz, 7z, rar or any other compression format that could be recognized by 7z and zip, which resulted in success in opening it with 7z, yet it doesn't means it's zip.

Comment: thanks glee but --how to check which format it is it has compressed  it has .File extension, I need to unpack it pragmatically using java,,

Comment: I checked its opening fine in terminal using tar -xvf MYFILE

Comment: Whose decision was it to make it a .File extension?  The whole point of the extension is to make it easy for you to tell what type of file it is.

Comment: I think then its originally a tar file. then.

Comment: I got the solution thanks for all. i am using Apache compress API to untar the package. thanks to MadProgrammer and Gkee8e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution thanks for all. i am using Apache compress API to untar the package. thanks to MadProgrammer and Gkee8e for giving direction.

```
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
```